# how to load schema file into Cassandra with cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a schema file for Cassandra. I'm using a windows 7 machine (Cassandra on this machien as well - 1 node). I want to load the schema with cqssh. So far I have not been able to find how. I was hoping to be able to pass the file to cqlsh: `cqlsh mySchemaFile`. However since I run in windows, to start cqlsh I do the following

```
python "C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin\cqlsh" localhost 9160
```

Even though I have csqsh in my path, when called like this from python it needs the full path.

I tried to add in there the file name but no luck so far. 
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cqlsh takes a file to execute via the `-f` or `--file` option, not as a positional argument (like the host and port), so the correct form would be:

```
python "C:\Program Files (x86)\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin\cqlsh" localhost 9160 -f mySchemaFile
```

Note: I'm not 100% sure about whether you'd use `-f` or `\f` in Windows.