# How to execute cassandra queries from a file

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Is it possible to run more than one Cassandra query from a single Cassandra file?

So that if I share that file, the others can run it to replicate the database in all systems

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to load schema file into Cassandra with cqlsh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750264/how-to-load-schema-file-into-cassandra-with-cqlsh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to pass the file containing CQL statements to either `cqlsh` (using the `-f` option) or using [DevCenter](http://www.datastax.com/download#dl-devcenter)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java, the Achilles framework has a class called ScriptExecutor that you can use to run CQL statements from a file and even plug in parameters to dynamically change the statements during execution.

[ScriptExecutor documentation](https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles/wiki/Unit-testing#script-executor)